# Why do the partial sums of the Maclaurin series expansion of $\sin$ approximate it better than their hyperbolic counterparts approximate $\sinh$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

While exploring Taylor series with numerical and graphing tools, I noticed a very peculiar and interesting fact: the partial sums of the Maclaurin series expansion of $\sin(x)$ approximate it better than their hyperbolic counterparts approximate $\sinh(x)$. To be specific, I noticed that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the following inequality *seems*  (haven't proven it) to hold

$$\left|\sin(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{k}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right|\leq\left|\sinh(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right|$$

For all $x\neq 0$, the inequality is strict, showing that $\sum_{n=0}^{k}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ does indeed approximate $\sin(x)$ better than $\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ approximates $\sinh(x)$. But *why* do they provide better approximations? The remainders

$$\sin(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{k}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!},\text{ }\sinh(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

obviously can't be equal everywhere, but given the similarity between the partial sums for each function, it's unclear to me why the $\sin$ remainder should be bounded by an inequality as "uniform" as the one above. Why isn't it the other way around, with $\sinh$'s remainder being bounded by $\sin$'s? Why is the inequality true for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and not just some disjoint intervals? Looking at the partial sums for each series, it can be seen that the only difference is the $(-1)^n$ factor for the $\sin$'s series, which doesn't seem like the kind of thing that can make the difference between

$$\left|\sin(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{k}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right|\leq\left|\sinh(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right|$$

and some other inequality relating the two remainders. Can someone give an intuitive explanation for why this happens?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The series for $\sin x$ is alternating. So for any given partial sum $T_n(x)$ of that series, the absolute value of the next term is an *overestimate* of the error in using $T_n(x)$ to estimate $\sin x$.

In contrast, the terms in the series for $\sinh x$ all have the same sign. So for any given partial sum $H_n(x)$ of that series, the absolute value of the next term is an *underestimate* of the error in using $H_n(x)$ to estimate $\sinh x$.

But for both series, the absolute value of the $n+1$st term is $\dfrac{|x|^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)!}$.

Comment: @AlannRosas: If you like! It depends on whether you want to start counting at 0 or 1.

Comment: THe sin series is not only alternating but enveloping.